# How to use UI bootstrap dropdown with Angular JS and inside ng-repeat with dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, toggle, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my case, I want to render the bootstrap dropdown menu inside an ng-repeat and also it has to bind to data from API. 
My code is,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs list clearfix" id="myTab">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="#">Home & Garden</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories" class="item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            id="dropdownMenu{{$index}}"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="true">
                {{$index}}<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu{{$index}}">
            <li ng-repeat="a in category.subcategories">
                <a href="#">{{a.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My controller code to get data from API call is,

```
$scope.getCategories = function () {
        userService.getCategories($rootScope.UrlProvider.categoriesList).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.success === true) {
                $scope.categories = response.data.categories;
            }
            else {
                $rootScope.showFailureMsg($rootScope.resourcesData.GenericErrorMessage);
            }
        });
    }
```

This `getCategories()` will be called on ng-init.

In this when the parent array "$scope.categories" is static ($scope.categories=[1,2,3,4,5]), the dropdown toggle is working. But when its value is from API $http call success callback, the dropdown toggle is not working. Can you please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of what your `$http` call looks like?

Comment: @machinehead115: Please refer my edit for the $http call.

Comment: I created a [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bD5WIAhTLLMjcU4Jqwkc?p=preview) with what you provided above, and made a mock `$http` request, and it seems to be working alright there. Compare between that and yours to see what's different. Also is your response coming back in the way that you expect it to?